# How can I get "go mod tidy" to create my module without odd version error?

Tags: go, module, dependencies

Go newbie here... I'm trying to create a new module, but "go mod tidy" is giving me a very strange error:

```
$ go mod init mymodule
go: creating new go.mod: module mymodule
go: to add module requirements and sums:
        go mod tidy

$ go mod tidy
go: finding module for package github.com/gin-gonic/gin
go: downloading github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.9.1
go: found github.com/gin-gonic/gin in github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.9.1
go: downloading github.com/gin-contrib/sse v0.1.0
[ snip ]
go: mymodule/src/pkg/mod/github.com/davecgh/go-spew@v1.1.1/spew: import path "mymodule/src/pkg/mod/github.com/davecgh/go-spew@v1.1.1/spew" should not have @version
go: mymodule/src/pkg/mod/github.com/modern-go/concurrent@v0.0.0-20180306012644-bacd9c7ef1dd: import path "mymodule/src/pkg/mod/github.com/modern-go/concurrent@v0.0.0-20180306012644-bacd9c7ef1dd" should not have @version
go: mymodule/src/pkg/mod/github.com/pmezard/go-difflib@v1.0.0/difflib: import path "mymodule/src/pkg/mod/github.com/pmezard/go-difflib@v1.0.0/difflib" should not have @version
```

Recreating go.mod doesn't help. Removing the src/pkg directory doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong? I'm stumped.

Comment: The error message is self explanatory: Remove the version from your import paths. Please take the Tour of Go and read and follow the tutorials in go.dev/doc.

Comment: The thing is, I don’t remember ever importing these modules, let alone adding version information.

Comment: Why are there references to `mymodule/src/pkg/mod`? Do you have your GOPATH located inside your module? A [mre] would show all the steps you did to get into this situation

Comment: https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/getting-started There's a ton of material online these days and quality and recency varies widely.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: Never create a directory named "pkg" in your build tree.

Rookie mistake.